# Kettle: How to get max date for each group of rows

Tags: etl, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I'm reading an excel sheet using Kettle and this sheet has three fields: code, description and date.

**Example**:

```
1 - description A - 01/JAN/2013
2 - description A - 15/JAN/2013
3 - description A - 04/JAN/2013
4 - description B - 02/JAN/2013
5 - description B - 16/JAN/2013
6 - description B - 11/JAN/2013
```

What I want is to put an additional field *Max date* for each row, where max date is the latest date on a group based on description, like this:

**Example 2**

```
1 - description A - 01/JAN/2013 - 15/JAN/2013
2 - description A - 15/JAN/2013 - 15/JAN/2013
3 - description A - 04/JAN/2013 - 15/JAN/2013
4 - description B - 02/JAN/2013 - 16/JAN/2013
5 - description B - 16/JAN/2013 - 16/JAN/2013
6 - description B - 11/JAN/2013 - 16/JAN/2013
```

The group of rows with *description A* has the latest date 15/JAN/2013 (because of row 2).
The group of rows with *description B* has the latest date 16/JAN/2013 (because of row 5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the perfect job for the row denormalizer step:

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Row+denormaliser

Comment: Agreed - This step is confusing to use though, so check the samples and all will become clear!

Comment: I'll try the row de-normalizer!

Comment: Wouldn't denormalizer result in only 1 record for all records with same key(so in the example result would be only 2 records instead of 6)? Should be row denormalizer used to get max value and then some merge to stick this value to every record with same key?

Comment: getting the "description" column as key will return merged values , see the doc link sample

Answer (score 1):

It's actually easier just to split your data in two streams (copy to consecutive steps) use stream 1 using the Group Step and base the group on the description and set as aggregate max value to find the maximum date for each group (should result in two output rows based on your example).

```
description A - 15/JAN/2013
description B - 16/JAN/2013
```

Next you use for stream 2 a Stream look-up Step to look up the max_date aggregate from the Group Step - stream 1 as use the description fields as key fields and use max_date aggregate as the value to retrieve.

Remember as you use the group step, it's necessary to sort your data accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using `Max` as an array formula.

So, suppose you had your original data in columns A thru C in your sheet, in cell `D1`, you would type:

```
=MAX(--($B$1:$B$4=B1)*($C$1:$C$4))
```

And then, to make it an array formula, you hit **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**

Of course, change the range for columns B & C to match your dataset.

Hope this helps and makes sense.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear, but I need a solution using Kettle, an ETL tool.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Good luck!!